# Javascript prototype or not

Tags: javascript, prototype

I saw below code on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/) can anyone, please tell me how `myArray.myMethod`  will work?

```
const myArray = ['zero', 'one', 'two'];
myArray.myMethod = function (sProperty) {
    console.log(arguments.length > 0 ? this[sProperty] : this);
};

myArray.myMethod(); // prints "zero,one,two"
myArray.myMethod(1); // prints "one"
```

Comment: If you've seen that on MDN then there will be an explanation anywhere on that same site. Also... If `myMethod` was a method on the prototype of `Array` it would be available on any array and not only on `myArray`. Should be easy to test.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work).

Comment: Where exactly did you see this code on MDN? Please link the page.

Comment: No, it's not a prototype, or a prototype method

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

### Background

The class in javascript is something like using [Prototype pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) to create objects. `Objects` that instance from a `class` have a common prototype, this means that these objects will contain the functions or properties of theirs prototype "object", you can regard this `prototype object` as only one special object for the class.

### Array

In this background, you need to understand that every `array object` is a "copy" from a `prototype` array object, it has all functions like `forEach()`, `map()`, and so on.

But this object is still an object, it is different from the prototype object, so when you use code

```js
const myArray = ['zero', 'one', 'two'];
const myArray1 = ['three', 'four', 'five'];
myArray.myMethod = new function(){...};
myArray.myMethod();
// myArray1.myMethod(); is undefined.
```

It will add a new function named `myMethod()` to the object `myArray`, and it will only affect the object `myArray`, the `myArray1` **does not** have the function `myMethod()`.

While if you use code

```js
const myArray = ['zero', 'one', 'two'];
const myArray1 = ['three', 'four', 'five'];
Array.prototype.myMethod = function(){console.log("myMethod")};
myArray.myMethod();
myArray1.myMethod();
```

it will add the function `myMethod()` to both `myArray` and `myArray1` because this time we add a function to their `prototype object`.